# Disable Particle rotation in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use Three.js to create an ’asteroid field' using particle systems or point clouds or stuff like that. One of the problems I've bumped into with all of these is that when the camera rotates around the z axis, the particles rotate individually with the camera, preserving the same orientation no matter how the camera is turned. I want the simulation to look as if the user is flying through a bunch of asteroids, and obviously asteroids don't magically spin whenever you tilt your head, so I was wondering if there is any way to prevent them from turning when the camera turns. Must particles always be upright?

Comment: Do you correctly understand difference between 3D mesh and a sprite?

Comment: @Martin I think so... Is there any way to make a large group of 3d objects that can be controlled individually?

Comment: what does mean 'the particles rotate individually with the camera, preserving the same orientation no matter how the camera is turned' ?
did you mean, particles are moving in space when camera rotate (pointcloud object rotate with camera), or you have each particle some image and wondering why is still faced to the camera, but each particle is on the same place during camera rotation / move?

Comment: @Martin More like the second option. The images always stay upright no matter how the camera turns, whereas I want the particles to behave like they would if they were an actual object that doesn't always appear right way up no matter how you look at it. Alternately, is there any way to set the rotation of a particle?

Comment: As i said Do you correctly understand difference between 3D mesh and a sprite? This is standard behavior of sprite, because of is rendered in 2D space. I'm not sure if rotation of sprite image will help you. It will rotate as image, not as object.

Comment: @Martin 2d rotation of the sprite image would be fine. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate sprites you can use attribute SpriteMaterial.rotation:

```
 var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture,rotation: Math.PI/4}));
```

see this http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html

In your case, rotation of all sprites should be equal to camera rotation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is sort of a separate question (which I've tried asking but no one has answered), but how do you rotate the particles individually (I would like them to point randomly in different directions)? I've read that this has something to do with shaders and custom attributes, but I don't really know how to use that so it would be great if there was an easier solution or if you could explain how to implement the shaders properly.

Comment: You should ask a right questions, but i think all of this including separate particle rotation is included in example http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html

Comment: It seems that the example in the link above uses THREE.Group instead of THREE.PointCloud, which leads to other problems when applied to my code. Is there any way to do the same thing for a PointCloud?